# How to extract a database from a text file (word or libreoffice) with styles and content

Tags: r, ms-word, survey, libreoffice-writer

I ask my question after searching an answer on stackoverflow and on the web, without success.
I'm sorry if there is already an answer somewhere.

**Global objective**

I aim to create my questionnaires in libreoffice ( I need to print it, it's not for an online survey), and secondly to use it in a R shiny app I've created for register the collected answers and to export the data.

*I want to create the fields in R (questions, answers...) automatically from the styles of my questionnaires in .odt, .docx or others formats.*

I need to have well formatted questionnaires, nice-looking.

**There is the problem:**

I have written a questionnaire on a libreoffice .odt file (or if necessary in microsoft word).
I uses styles for different text blocks: one style for the "questions", one for the "answer", one for the parts of the questionnaire, one for the "instructions"...
I want to get a database ( in .csv format) with one column with the styles, and one column with the text content.

**Solutions?**

- I try to open the xml files in the .odt or .docx archives, but the conversion to a simpler and readable format seems quite difficult.
- Is it possible to export a toc from libreoffice or word to a spreadsheet format?
- R can read in such files (.odt or .dox, or.xml) ?

Thank you very much for your ideas, and more generaly for your feedbacks on my project.

I'm sorry for my english

Comment: `word_document` output format for R Markdown lets you specify a `docx` file (_not_ a word template file) with defined styles [as a base document](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/word_document_format#style_reference). The [`officer` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/officer/index.html) lets you programmatically create word docs that can also be have an existing document as a base for styles.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thank you! The officer package is my solution. I can read in docx files and use the content in a shiny app according to the styles.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `.Rmd` (for `rmarkdown`) or `.Rnw` (for `knitr`) files as the source for your questionaires, rather than starting with .odt or .docx.  You can produce output in various formats, including `.docx`, `.pdf`, `.html` (only `.pdf` for `.Rnw`) to display the questionaire to the subjects, but you can also develop functions to manage the data, or even interactive displays to collect and record the data.

I'm not familiar with R packages that do all of this for you, but I expect they already exist.  Maybe someone else will give an answer with more details.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Knitr and markdown are very useful, but in a context of collaborative work on the questionnaires with others persons familiar to the usual word processors, I prefer work for common words or libreoffice documents....

Answer (score 0):

You might explore using the [.fodt format in libreOffice Writer](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/ODF_Markup). That format is an "unzipped" version of the Writer xml format, so could be directly readable by xml utilities (and probably R, with appropriate libraries). I note that for another answer you seemed to want to avoid markdown or knitr composition, and .fodt would provide a "text" format completely compatible with LibreOffice as a front end.

(Note the other parts of LibreOffice have "flat" versions, so you could, in theory, process text versions of spreadsheets, graphics, and presentation files in your R utility.)

A few web searches indicates some relevant libraries and utilities for R exist, which may get you closer to what you need for your project.